# Restart Online Computer in Teamviewer without Log In

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, reboot, teamviewer

I have Teamviewer installed on the target machine as a service so it can work unattended. I was using it just fine and then suddenly I got kicked from the session. Now when I try to reconnect a session it says "This session is finished."

Is there anyway that I can get Teamviewer to restart the machine without having to actually log in?

Tried other methods like CMD `shutdown -r -f -m \\my.ip`. I'm open to any other suggestions. I do have remote access to my router if that can help me at all.

Is it possible to send a restart packet in the same way that WOL sends a startup packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Teamviewer to VPN to the remote computer. From here you can use the shutdown -r command specifying the IP address of the remote machine specified in the Teamviewer VPN window.

Comment: It seems I can't make a VPN connection from my computer. I assume it's blocked at work. I made a VPN connection from my phone using the built in Asus VPN of my router. Any suggestions how to reboot from that?

Comment: Use Teamviewer or RDP app from your phone, buy you will need to log in to remote computer.

Comment: Logging in is not possible. Gives me the same error.

Comment: Tethering your work PC to your phone and running the shutdown command for the remote pc may work.

Comment: While it won't help you now, you could set up outlook to run on the remote computer with a rule to run a program on receiving a certain type of email i.e. from your email address with subject = "Shutdown PC" which runs a .bat file containing 'shutdown -r -f -t 0'

Comment: Tried the VPN/Tether but didn't seem to work. Thank you though